# how to display < html tags without escaping nightmare

Tags: html

I want to be able to indicate a part of the HTML file where i can simply type `<asd><qwe>` and they will be displayed as such (i mean the text).

I am aware we can do this: `<asd><qwe>` but it slowly becomes a nightmare..

I tried:

```
<pre><asd><qwe></pre>
```

but it isn't working..

Comment: Please fix your code block, it's coming up empty. You could just write out the html, copy and paste it into another file where you can then do a find and replace to use the html entity codes instead. Then copy and paste it back.

Answer (score 1):

HTML 4.x (technically) supports CDATA sections (which do what you want), but browsers don't (except in XHTML served as application/xhtml+xml which isn't supported by IE < 9).

Use `&lt;` and friends. An editor with Find & Replace stops it being a nightmare.

Answer (score 1):

Why not use an online tool like Quick Escape: http://accessify.com/tools-and-wizards/developer-tools/quick-escape/

Write whatever you would like without escaping it.  Then copy and paste it into Quick Escape and it will return it escaped.

Answer (score 0):

Replace all you `<` by `&lt;` (lt = less than) and all your `>` by `&gt;` (gt = greater than).

If you're using some PHP, you can simply use `htmlentities()`, which will do that alone.

Answer (score 0):

Escaping HTML special characters (not just < and > but several others as well) is your only option I'm afraid.  However there's quite a few editors that can do this for you

Answer (score 0):

Technically you can put you data in a `<![CDATA[...]]>` construct. However, it is poorly supported by browsers, so you have to live with the escaping.
You best option is probably to use an editor that can help you escaping.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is incredible vague but you are probably looking for about the [`<XMP></XMP>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/HTML/Element/xmp) tag set. However, such element has been deprecated for quite long: you can use it for some quick testing but it has no place in a live site.

The only serious approach is to use a server-side language that takes care of escaping for you.

Answer (score 0):

See you have two options :

- In your text editor "Find and Replace All" all "<" with "<" and all ">" with ">"
- And as posted by Oltarus, if your server supports php then just use:

  `<?php echo htmlentities("<html><head></head></html>"); ?>`