# Escape html tags between <code> </code>

Tags: html

is there any reliable way to escape html tags between <code> and <\code>, without having to take the detour of using &lt; &gt; ...?

Cheers, Beejay!

Comment: With javascript or PHP ? or only HTML ?

Comment: You mean when writing HTML by hand? No.

Comment: @Roadirsh: Nah, just talking plain HTML

Comment: @deceze Too  bad. You say writing by hand, what alternatives would you know if I were not writing by hand?

Comment: Where are the inner html tags created? .. static in a html file on server or do you use ASP or PHP?

Comment: @PellePenna static in a html file, usually. I do sometimes work with JSF though. Does that make any difference?

Comment: If you use server side code you can easily have the inner html code in a separate file and when read and injected into the code tags, you run the file content through a htmlencode() method, which will do the work for you

Comment: @PellePenna: OK, great. As for client side code, like deceze said, no chance?

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to display < html tags without escaping nightmare](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6519650/how-to-display-html-tags-without-escaping-nightmare)

Comment: Why is the question marked as unclear what I'm asking? Apparently at least 3 users, know exactly what I'm talking about!

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure if that is what you wanted, but check this out using "xmp" tag

```
<code> <xmp> <P> testing </p> </xmp> </code>
```

Output is:

```
<P> testing </p>
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/MMDH5/)

Comment: One thing to bear in mind though is that the `xmp` tag [is deprecated](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html32#xmp).

Comment: You're right it is! I though because browsers still support it, it would be ok to introduce it as an answer.

Comment: This is a good answer, however I thought I'll just point it out for anyone planning to use it :)

Comment: This is actually really great and exactly what I was looking for. Too bad it's deprecated. Why would anyone deprecate such a useful tag..